# How to find what the problem in my AWS CodePipeline is when the failure says "Reason: No reason was provided"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

I created a Lambda application using the AWS wizard that sets up a repo and CodePipeline for building and deploying:

[image]

After I added some attributes to my sam `template.yaml` and I added values for them to the CodePipeline (possibly in the wrong place, I don't know, trying to figure that out), I ended up with this failure:

[image]

If I click on "Details" on the step that failed, the last one, I see this:

[image]

which isn't very helpful. Clicking "Link to execution details" takes me to this:

[image]

and other than the red "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE" I don't see any other errors anywhere, on any tabs.

The "AWS CloudFormation" link takes me here:

[image]

which just links to the previous screen.

Where else can I go to find what's going on here? to find an error message I could read and try to solve?

Comment: Go to `Events` in cloud formation for the stack that failed and search for what exactly failed and why.

Comment: How did you go? What does `Events` say?

Comment: what did you change in your template?